# Indexing specific DocumentDB types of entities

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Since Microsoft chose to set a minimum of 400RUs per DocumentDB collection, their pricing structure guides developers into creating collections based on RU requirements rather than a set of collections that represent a logical data model.
i.e. one might create a set of collections that require high query cost/throughput  (1000RUs), a medium (600RUs), and a low RU(400 RUs).  Each of these collections could contain multiple types of entities.

However, collection-based indexing would seem to hamper that approach.  If entity A and entity B are stored in the same collection and both contain a 'Name' attribute, additional indexing may not be beneficial on both of those entities.  It's not clear to me how to get around this limitation.

One could create a collection for each type of document that requires any additional indexing but that feels wasteful as well.  I would likely be creating collections that don't represent the projected spending.

Is there a better approach to indexing documents with DocumentDB?

Comment: I know it will sound like a hack but you can get around that by wrapping your documentdb entity on it's own model name and add a policy specifically for it so the paths would look like `/users/name` with whatever indexing you want and then `/cars/name` again, with whatever rules you want. Does this make sense?

Comment: That would work.  We'd need to update our serializer but that should be doable.  It would be nice if a hack like that wouldn't be necessary but I can't think of a better approach.

Comment: I came across the same issue when I was developing my CosmosDB object mapper, and i just couldn't come up with something better.

Answer (score 1):

**DocumentDB is schemaless**, I would say ability to insert documents with whatever schema and have indexes which don't care about document "type" within the same collection is very much by intentional design. There's little point in fighting it.

The design allows you to have as many (or few) collections as you feel is the best for performance/maintenance/data organization needs. You can seamlessly start with one collection and transfer N types to another should you feel that the extra cost is justified. So **you CAN build a "set of collections that represent a logical data model"** if you are willing to pay for the provisioned extra RU's - having a single pool from which to handle peaks is usually cheaper than N smaller ones, so by splitting you have to overprovision more to be safe. But it's your choice.

About indexes - if you need to store 2 entities with same property name then **design your model so they'd have different path** and hence could be differentiated in queries and indexes. IT does make sense for relational DB mindset as well: don't store different facts in the same data field. Technically you could do this, but it usually bites back soon.

Having a **differently named parent container for each "type"** is the simplest and rather futureproof way to differentiate types as it allows you to add or transfer "types" between collection and still avoid index conflict. On the other hand make sure do keep "cross-type" fields in uniform location for unified indexes, for example audit fields or globally unique keys.

As always, data design dictates what you can or cannot do.